# What is the meaning of あるある?

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang

I saw it used on Twitter several times, but googling around I couldn't figure it out.

Here are some examples.

> "@mao_sid: 24あるある。シーズン2ぐらいから、あのちょいちょい入ってくるデジタル時計いらないなぁって思いだす。"
>
> "@mao_sid: 24あるある。ジャックは忙しくなると基本、大統領以外にはタメ口になる。"
>
> "@mao_sid: 24あるある。たまに他の海外ドラマに出てる俳優さんが出てくると嬉しくなる。"

It looks like this is about the TV show "24." But I don't understand the あるある part.

Comment: あるある is in every online dictionary. I just found it in three different ones. Voting to close based on not having met the minimum requirement of research before asking here.

Comment: I already saw it in the dictionary but the dictionary definition doesn't make sense. I think it means something else other than what's found in the dictionary.

Comment: I asked the question here, and you see, it doesn't seem to have anything to do with the dictionary definition. http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1380927028

Comment: So remove your vote to close now. And next time don't assume that I didn't check the dictionary because I always do. I have rikaichan installed.

Comment: Just because you found another person on the planet who is also incapable of looking it up in a dictionary doesn't mean the question isn't solvable by looking it up in a dictionary. Also, my vote to close represents my opinion of this question, so it's not something that you get to insist I take away. I still think it should be closed.

Comment: Sorry, whether or not he should have voted to close aside, demanding that he remove the vote is bad form.

Comment: Even after looking up あるある, I wasn't completely sure what 24あるある meant. So I think it's a valid question.

Comment: @DaveMG *Another* person that is *incapable* of looking in the dictionary? That person I asked was a native Japanese speaker. They don't need to look in the dictionary. And even if they did, it wouldn't have helped because I already did and it didn't make sense. I already wrote that I checked, or did you miss that? Do you only see what you want to see? Do you know what rikaichan is? When you look at the dictionary definition and then look at the context, does it make sense to you?

Comment: @DaveMG This seems like a completely valid question to me...Just being in a dictionary doesn't always mean it's clear to everyone.  And seeing how this site is in beta and falls way below the numerical goals of StackExchange as listed in Area51, I think it might be in the best interest of the site to try and make everyone feel welcome to ask questions, and not berate them...But what do I know, I'm just the new guy.

Comment: @DaveMG I looked at those questions.  I think what qualifies as a question here is just a bit too strict.  Really seems like you guys are narrowing down your potential audience.  This exchange of comments alone and seeing this question-poster berated has made me decide to stop coming here.  If your response to that is, "well go away then," then you clearly don't have the site overall in mind.  It just seems like a power trip to see who can follow the rules the closest, rather than actually encouraging an exchange of knowledge. I'm gonna go away now.  Have fun with your FAQs and strict rules.

Comment: People please: mind your language (just deleted some heated comments that crossed the line of civility). I think all parties have made their point, now either vote the question up if you like it, or vote-to-close if you think it doesn't belong here, but stop bickering and move on with your life!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In colloquial speech, 「あるある」 is basically a way to respond to questions like "Have you ever noticed how the more busy Jack gets, the more he sweats". あるある means something like "Yeah, I recognize that situation" or "Yeah, I've been thinking about that too" or "Yeah, I *have* noticed that".

One meaning of ネタ is 'humorous material' or 'joke material'. There's a term あるあるネタ, which basically means humorous questions like the above, which you can use in conversation as jokes.

Here, although I'm not familiar with Twitter lingo, I would guess that the poster is using 24あるある to refer to あるあるネタ about the TV show '24'. So basically "In 24, have you noticed how [...]".

Comment: Maybe beginners do not know that あるある is just ある/あります twice. And that, when speaking, repeating twice the same word is common.

Comment: I know that あるある=ある+ある, but knowing that alone is not enough to understand what it means.